# Magento2 : How to get product dimension units (cm/in)?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.3

I need to get the dimension units for width, height and length. There are solution available only to get the value of these attributes like,

```
$product->getTsDimensionsLength();
$product->getTsDimensionsWidth();
$product->getTsDimensionsHeight();
```

How can I get the dimension unit (like **cm** or **in**) for these values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will need an extension for this

Comment: @PhilippSander Since we can get the unit of weight (kgs/lbs), why is this not possible using built-in methods?

Answer (score 1):

Measurement unit comes from system configuration.

```
Stores -> Configurations -> General -> Locale Options -> Weight Unit
```

Please refer the link for the solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/276544/55658