# How to get the Unit of measure label of product attributes like weight,Length etc in product detail page?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, magento2.3.0, product-detail-page

How to get the Unit of measure label of product attributes like weight,Length etc in product detail page?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This settings comes from system configuration.

**Weight:** **Stores -> Configurations -> Generale -> Locale Options -> Weight Unit**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
```

Then

```
/**
 * @var ScopeConfigInterface
 */
private $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 */
public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
{
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
```

Get value:

```
$weightUnit = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/locale/weight_unit',
        ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
```

For dimension (width, length): here is the logic

> vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Dimensions.php

```
($weightUnit === 'kgs') ? 'cm' : 'in'
```

Comment: How to get it from product detail page?

Comment: Check updated answer